# Helpdesk option for normal users in open erp 7.0

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I would want to know that how can i add a helpdesk option for  a normal project/user.
I've tried it , i've added an item under group access rights, where module name is crm.helpdesk.

I've tried it for portal user too but for those user i also not able to find this helpdesk option.

I am a nontechnical person but able to understand if you will help to dig out from this problem.

Please help me to find out this solution.

Answer (score 0):

helpdesk means crm_helpdesk? just install crm_helpdesk module and give permissions to users like this:

give following rights to usr when u creating user by settings>users>create....

```
Application
Sales=User: Own Leads Only
Human Resources=Employee
Sharing=User
Administration=
```

Comment: thanks for your help.But this is not working.Can you please tell that what should i take in administration= ?